# How to get the HWND of the taskbar MSTaskListWClass?

Tags: c++, winapi

How i could retrieve the `MSTaskListWClass` `hWnd`?

I mean the "Running applications" tool bar which shows the button of each window in the taskbar.

[image]

I have tried to get it with:

```
HWND mstask = FindWindow(L"MSTaskListWClass", NULL);
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

But `mstask` return null, `err` outputs `0`

Comment: Hey @Raja what tool are you using here to show the window classes. My Spy++ on Windows 11 looks very different.

Comment: @Wayne inspect.exe, its from an old microsoft sdk, i cant remember which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindWindowW` retrieves a handle to the top-level windows only. not for child windows. so need first search for parent window -  "Shell_TrayWnd" and than use `EnumChildWindows`

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChild(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WCHAR name[32];
    if (GetClassNameW(hwnd, name, _countof(name)) && !wcscmp(name, L"MSTaskListWClass"))
    {
        *(HWND*)lParam = hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

HWND GetMSTaskListW()
{
    HWND hwnd = 0;
    if (HWND hWndParent = FindWindowW(L"Shell_TrayWnd", 0))
    {
        EnumChildWindows(hWndParent, EnumChild, (LPARAM)&hwnd);
    }

    return hwnd;
}
```